# Prove the number of solutions a function has?

Tags: roots

What methods/theorems are commonly used when trying to prove that a function has exactly one root within a given interval $(a,b)$, or that it has no roots?

I have the function $f(x)=\dfrac1x-\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x}$. It is a strictly increasing function that is not defined for $a$ nor $b$....

Would just like a hint.

Comment: root = crosses the x axis.

Comment: It's a bit more advanced than that, buddy. I need to use the mean value theorem and intermedia value theorem; only problem is that the function is not defined for a nor b, so I'm not sure how I can do some of the calculations.

Comment: Can you tell us anything else about this function?  Can you give us the explicit form of $f(x)$?  If not, do we know that the function is continuous?  Do we know that it has a limit at a or b, and what those limits are?

Answer (score 0):

Using the expression of $f$ you gave in a comment above to explain a method:

$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x\sin x} = \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}-(x-\frac{x^3}{2}) +o(x^3)}{x\sin x} = \frac{\frac{2x^3}{6}+o(x^3)}{x^2+o(x^2)}\sim \frac{x}{3} $$
when $x\to 0$. Your function can thus be extended by continuity on $a=0$. Show you can also do that at $b=\pi$ (not even necessary in your case), and then apply the mean value theorem or your machinery of choice.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x) = 1/x - \cos(x)/\sin(x)$.  Note that, with the restriction of $x \in (0,\pi), x \neq \pi/2$,
$$
1/x - \cos(x)/\sin(x) = 0 \iff\\
\frac{\sin(x) - x\cos(x)}{x \sin(x)} = 0 \iff\\
\sin(x) - x\cos(x) = 0 \iff\\
\tan(x) - x = 0
$$
So, it suffices to show that $g(x) = \tan(x) - x$ has no roots on this interval.  In order to do so, it suffices to note that $g$ is continuous and strictly increasing on the intervals where it's defined, and that we have the following limits:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}g(x) = 0\\
\lim_{x \to \pi/2^-}g(x) = \infty\\
\lim_{x \to \pi/2^+}g(x) = -\infty\\
\lim_{x \to \pi^-}g(x) < 0
$$

Comment: Hi. I was thinking about the fact that it's strictly increasing: can I combine that with the limits so that if I have (a,b) - and it's not defined for a and b, but the limit as I approach a from the right = negative number and the limit as I approach b from the right = positive number, then as it's strictly increasing within (a,b), it must have at least one root? Can I use this argument with the limits?

Comment: Nope, the conclusion you should reach is that there are no roots on the interval.  Namely, use these facts to show that $g$ (and therefore $f$) can't have any zeros on $(0,\pi/2)$ or $(\pi/2,\pi)$.  Then note that $f(\pi/2)$ isn't zero.  So, $f$ can't have any zeros on the interval.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. I got the point that it has no roots on the interval. Let me rephrase: Imagine a function that is increasing on the interval (0,a), but it is not defined for x = 0. How can I "prove" that it is always positive on the interval (0,a), if I cannot show that f(0) > 0? This is why I was asking if I could show something using limits, but I am not sure.

Comment: You can. See my answer below: $f$ can be extended by continuity into a $g$ which is continuous, has $g(0)=0$, and $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in (0,\pi)$. You can also prove similarly that $g$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi)$, which gives you what you want.

Comment: @Daniel the problem with your question is that the way that you "prove" however many roots a function has varies wildly depending on the convenient properties of the function.  I will, however, say this: if $f$ is defined on $(0,a)$, if it is strictly increasing wherever it is defined, and if $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$, then we can indeed say that $f$ will have no roots on $(0,a)$.

Comment: All right thanks. I think I understand it somewhat now.